# Search Replace in array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a array i want to to replace a particular value if exists in the array with a specific value .

**Array**

```
my @array_list = ('TEST12','TEST14','TEST','TEST23');
```

What i have tried is :

```
foreach (@array_list) { 
    if($_ eq "TEST"){
        $_ =~ s/$_/HT/;
    }
 }
```

Is there any other better way to do this .Please help me in this

Comment: `@array_list = map { $_ eq 'TEST' ? 'HT' : $_ } @array_list`

Comment: Or another... `@array_list = map { s/^TEST$/HT/; $_ } @array_list`

Comment: @DavidO while this works, it has side effect when assigning to another array as `$_` inside map is aliased to original array.

Comment: @mpapec Yes but we assign back to the original, nullifying the side-effect. :)  But you're correct; if we wanted to make it safe in a general sense, we would make a copy before the substitution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you just want to do in-place replacement of the single exact match:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array_list = ('TEST12','TEST14','TEST','TEST23');

$_ eq 'TEST' and $_ = 'HT' for @array_list;

use Data::Dump;
dd @array_list;
```

Outputs:

```
("TEST12", "TEST14", "HT", "TEST23")
```

Can accomplish the same with a regex as well:

```
s/\ATEST\z/HT/ for @array_list;
```